# How Do I Pass Which Item I Want To Delete?

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I've inherited this code and fairly new to Laravel.  But we have a cart and we can add items to the cart.  But the part to delete items from the cart isn't working.  Each line has a delete Remove button.  But somehow needs to pass to the controller which item it needs to remove.
the cart.blade.php has:
                @foreach($custom_quote_items as $custom_quote_item)

```
            <tr>

                <td><p>{{ $custom_quote_item->name }}</p></td>
                <td><p>{{ $custom_quote_item->description }}</p></td>
                <td><p>{{ intval($custom_quote_item->quantity) }}</p></td>
                <td><p>{{ $custom_quote_item->pricing($custom_quote_item->name) }}</p></td>
                <td>
                    <p>
                        {{ Form::open(array('action' => 'CustomQuoteController@removeFromQuote', 'method' => 'DELETE')) }}

                        {{ Form::hidden('id', $custom_quote_item->id) }}

                        {{ Form::submit('Remove', array('class'=>'btn btn-default')) }}

                        {{ Form::close() }}
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>

            @endforeach
```

The CustomQuoteController.php has

```
    public function removeFromQuote()
    {

    $item_exists = true;

    //          $custom_quote_item = CustomQuoteItem::find(Input::get('id'));
     $custom_quote_item = CustomQuoteItem::find(Input::get('name'));
      //            $custom_quote_item = CustomQuoteItem::find(197);
     print(Input::get('id'));
        print("End NAME\n");
        $custom_quote_items = Session::get('custom_quote_items');

        if(count($custom_quote_items) > 0 )
        {

            foreach($custom_quote_items as $key => $item_in_cart)
            {
            dd($item_in_cart);

            if($item_in_cart->name == $custom_quote_item->name)
                {

                    unset($custom_quote_items[$key]);

                    Session::set('custom_quote_items', $custom_quote_items);

                    return Redirect::back()->with('success', 'Item has been removed.');

                }

            }

        }

        return Redirect::back()->with('errors', 'Item was not removed.');

    }

}
```

The line: $custom_quote_item = CustomQuoteItem::find(Input::get('id')); returns back null so I know the id isn't working but neither is the name.  So figured it's on the blade side.

Comment: Can you verify if the values of the hidden inputs are getting set appropriately?

Comment: in your cart.blade.php, if you just output {{ $custom_quote_item->id }}, does it show the id? and what do you see if you put at the start of your removeFromQuote() this line: `dd(Input::all());`

Comment: The output of the id is blank.  I think they messed up and should have used name to key on.  The output of the dd in the RemoveFromQuote is:  array (size=3)
  '_method' => string 'DELETE' (length=6)
  '_token' => string 'HRRyyx5PibIyPHHlzT8uCHafuqRJue8r98bBfIbo' (length=40)
  'id' => string '' (length=0)    It should use name as it it the item we need to search for in the database which should return back the id of the item to remove.  I manually put in the number of the item in the database and it will work once I am able to pass the name from the blade to the controller right.

Comment: So you are not filling the "id" hidden input field. -- if you want to use the name for finding the item instead, you might try this in cart.blade.php `{{ Form::hidden('name', $custom_quote_item->name) }}` and then in your method `$custom_quote_item = CustomQuoteItem::where('name', Input::get('name'))->first();` (that might be tricky, as i assume, your "name" isn't unique identificator)

Comment: Rozklad that worked.  On the blade I changed it to {{ Form::hidden('name', $custom_quote_item->name) }}  and on the controller $custom_quote_item = CustomQuoteItem::where('name', Input::get('name'))->first();